# How to call withColumn function dynamically over dataframe in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is this possible in spark-scala? I am using spark 2.2

```
val func="""withColumn("seq", lit("this is seq"))
           .withColumn("id", lit("this is id"))
           .withColumn("type", lit("this is type"))"""
```

Then use the above variable on top of a dataframe (df) like this

```
val df2=df.$func
```

Reason I am saving those functions to a variable is that I want to apply functions dynamically based on conditions. Sometime I may want 1 withColumn and sometimes I may want multiple withColumn functions.

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood correctly, then you can do this using `foldLeft`

Let's suppose you have a `dataframe` df as

```
val df: DataFrame = Seq(("123"), ("123"), ("223"), ("223")).toDF()
```

You can create a `list` of column names and the operation/function that you call as

```
val list = List(
  ("seq", lit("this is seq")),
  ("id", lit("this is id")),
  ("type" , lit("thisis type"))
)
```

Now you can use `foldLeft` to use this list as

```
list.foldLeft(df){(tempDF, listValue) =>
  tempDF.withColumn(listValue._1, listValue._2)
}
```

Better solution is to create a select statement from list of above values and columns from dataframe as below

```
val columns = df.columns.map(col) ++ list.map(r => r._2 as r._1)
```

Final Result:

```
+-----+-----------+----------+-----------+
|value|seq        |id        |type       |
+-----+-----------+----------+-----------+
|123  |this is seq|this is id|thisis type|
|123  |this is seq|this is id|thisis type|
|223  |this is seq|this is id|thisis type|
|223  |this is seq|this is id|thisis type|
+-----+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Shankar!! Is there a way to dynamically execute a statement in spark? I mean if I prepare the statement and store in a variable, can i execute it?

Comment: Like what kind of statement you want to store on a variable? If its a function that you want to apply, you surely can use it

Comment: like, I have a mix of operations like "withColumn" and "select" operations to be performed on a df and they may vary based on my input. Any suggestion how i can approach to this?

Comment: I don't think that can be achieved because they are functions and they can't be called dynamically.

Comment: @koiralo could you please advice what is wrong here in reduce function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843599/reduce-result-datasets-into-single-dataset

Comment: @Lux If you have withColumn and select in the same statment, why not just construct a sql query?